# How to run node server using DEBUG command in docker file?

Tags: node.js, docker, express, debugging

What is the command of the running node server in docker using DEBUG? I tried following commands in dockerfile but no luck.

```
CMD [ "npm", "DEBUG=* start" ]

CMD [ "DEBUG=*", "npm", "start" ]
```

I am using [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) npm for logging.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Set the DEBUG environment car with ENV

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation on `npm debug`, it requires `DEBUG` to be an environment variable, like `set DEBUG=*,-not_this`. In this case you can do it in several ways:

Using `ENV` command of `Dockerfile`:

```
ENV DEBUG * start
```

or

```
ENV DEBUG="* start"
```

If you want to dynamically change the `DEBUG` variable, you can put it into `CMD` and override on container start, but in this case you have to follow your OS rules for environment variable definition. 
For Windows it can be:

```
CMD ["cmd.exe", "-c", "set DEBUG=* start"]
```